# How can i identify number of return of the ping in the sonar?

Tags: digital-communications, radar, sonar

I am writing a fake function which is actually doing active pinging (basically SONAR). I am little confuse here about how to identify the number of sonar return i got ? Let's say i am continuously send square wave for active pinging ? How to identify that for which number of ping i get the return ?

Comment: A fake function?  It sounds pretty real to me.

Comment: You do realize that what you're asking for is basically everything you need to know to do sonar signal processing.  Have you looked for a book on the subject?

Comment: @TimWescott - i have other parent system that uses the data of sonar for other processing. I’m just faking a data coming from my sonar and feed that data to my system. I did look at the book on the subject but not able to come to any conclusion for this.

Comment: It occurs to me that you may be asking for something simpler than it sounds.  Could you expand your question with a specific example of what you're trying, what you're seeing, and what you want to do with it?